# Negative strtotime

Tags: php

Having Europe/Amsterdam as timezone.
Why does:

```
strtotime("January 1, 1970 00:40:00');
```

returns

```
-1200
```

I don't get it.

Comment: Because Europe/Amsterdam is UTC+1, and `strtotime()` returns a UTC timestamp. "January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC+1" == -3600, 40mins == 2400s, and -3600 + 2400 == -1200.

Comment: @Sammitch so `strtotime("January 1, 1970 00:40:00 GMT+1");` would be a good fix?

Comment: No, that will still get you -1200. The zero-second UTC timestamp for your timezone is "January 1, 1970 01:00:00 GMT+1" and nothing is ever going to change that.

Comment: Strange, that does return 2400 which equals to 40 minutes...

Comment: @Sammitch how is that possible?

Comment: Um... because the universe did not begin as of [January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)? I thought that this was common knowledge...

Comment: Sorry, I ment UTC+1 in stead of GMT+1. You stated before that it still will get met -1200.

Answer (score 2):

Because, php counts time starting from `January 1, 1970 00:00:00` . So you are back from the reference time, That's the possible reason. So 1200 would be

> ( - 60*40 (+/-) time_difference_in_your_timezone)

Answer (score 0):

The strtotime function parses the strinf date into "into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC)". Please see the php documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The -1200 is caused by your time zone.
strtotime is calculating from `January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC`. If you calculate the date back from UTC+1 to UTC you are at December 31, 1969 23:40:00 UTC.